# git p4 sync - where did the perforce changes go?

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

In my current setup, all changes made in a Perforce depot are migrated to a git repo. The transfer is one way, always from Perforce to git, and never the other way around. I had no problem using `git p4 clone` to copy the depot into a new git repo, however, I'm now attempting to use `git p4 sync`, and my repo is not being updated.

When I ran `git p4 sync`, it did show status messages on importing new changes from the Perforce depot. If I run the command again, it says everything is up-to-date. My `master` branch does not have the changes, and there aren't any other branches or remotes listed in my repo (eg with `git branch -v` and `git remote -v`. How do I checkout these changes?

(using `git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is an implicit remote branch "`p4`" created. Thus, running `git pull p4/HEAD` will pull the latest changes from `git p4 sync` into your current branch. It can be listed by using `git branch --remotes` (thanks to @jamesdlin).

Comment: `p4` is a remote branch.  It's listed with `git branch --remotes`.

Comment: it says : p4/HEAD does not appear to be a git repository"

Comment: any solution yet?

Answer (score 8):

You want this:

$ git p4 rebase

Comment: I have some staged `D` changes I can't get rid of which is preventing this from being invoked. Man this is frustrating.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat just `git stash` them.

Answer (score 0):

This unexpectedly worked for me:

```
git reset --hard p4/master
```

Presumably you still have to run `git p4 sync` first.

I know this isn't ideal if you actually have changes you want to be retained.